# Find keyword, replace next value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input file I want to duplicate with some of the parameters changed. This is a simplified version of the input file:

```
Temperature = 100
Density = 8
Expansion factor = 1.0
```

I am trying to write a script that will search through the input file, find a keyword (e.g. temperature/density), then change the next value after the keyword. I have a series of for loops set up for each keyword but I can't work out how to edit the next value after the keyword. I think I need regex but this is all I have so far:

```
regex = r"Temperature\s(.*)"
re.findall(regex, file)
```

I would also like to ignore how many spaces there are in the input file if possible - e.g. these three lines would all appear the same:

```
Temperature        =    100
Temperature=100
Temperature = 100
```

If that's possible!

Comment: Are you looking for something like `r'Temperature[^\d]+(\d+)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```py
your_new_text = re.sub(r"(Temperature\s*=\s*)[^\n]+", "\\1TheNewValue", input_file.read())
```

should do the trick. Replace Temperature with whatever you are searching for and TheNewValue with whatever you want in it's place

Comment: How would I replace TheNewValue with a variable? E.g. if I have three temperatures and want to create a new input for each of them?